Umbraco - Duende server OpenIDconnect: InvalidOperationException
I have a Duende server and a web client and there aren't problems with the OpendID connection. I followed the documentations according this link https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v7.
Now I'm trying to connect Umbraco web client with my Duende server.
I followed this solution https://github.com/jbreuer/Umbraco-OpenIdConnect-Example/tree/main
After login,
In UmbracoBuilderExtensions.cs
the name is null ( rif. var name = claims?.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == "user_displayname"); )
and in UmbExternalLoginController.cs the loginInfo is null.
So, I have this error in the browser
InvalidOperationException: The Name value cannot be null
Some ideas?
Sergio

If the name is missing, then you need do some claim mapping. Look inside the ID-token and determine what the name of the name claim is.
So, if the name claim is named "name", then do this:
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    ...
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        RoleClaimType = "role"
    };
    ...
}

You can read more about this problem in my blog post here: Debugging OpenID Connect Claim Problems in ASP.NET Core

Thank you for the post. I found that it is an Umbraco bug, https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/issues/12670
I added a new NameClaimType. There is the same error, probably I put a wrong map claim. I let you know tomorrow. Thanks

Awesome, feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem :-)
